# Sorting Multidimensional Arrays Ruby by Count Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

So i have a multidimensional array in ruby which looks like this

```
[["34224", "1"],["20561", "1"],["26195", "1"],["32098", "1"],
 ["33375", "1"],["34077", "1"],["34219", "1"],["34220", "1"],
 ["34223", "1"],["19178", "1"],["33650", "1"],["33654", "1"],
 ["33715", "1"],["33716", "1"],["33966", "1"],["33967", "1"],
 ["33968", "1"],["34068", "1"],["34069", "1"],["34070", "1"],
 ["34071", "1"],["34072", "1"],["34073", "1"],["34074", "1"],
 ["34075", "1"],["34076", "1"],["33515", "2"],["33717", "2"],
 ["33852", "2"],["33965", "2"],["34222", "2"]]
```

Basically, the second value in each array is the count.

I wiant to get all the values in the array where the count is 1 and where the count is 2. I want to be able to sort them apart.

How do i do tht in the cleanest ruby way possible

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional arrays in Ruby (unless you count `Matrix` from the standard library), what you have is an array whose elements are arrays but a multi-dimensional array is quite a different beast.

Comment: Since this is tagged with "ruby-on-rails" – is that array the result of a database query? If so, please show the query, maybe the database can handle the grouping more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You're not talking about "sorting", you're talking about creating subsets.  In the easiest way, you can use the `last` method of an array to get the last value.  Here's what it looks like:

```
arr.select { |item| item.last == '1' }
arr.select { |item| item.last == '2' }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [group_by](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by):

```
array.group_by{|a| a.last}
```

Comment: I think `array.group_by(&:last)` - looks more pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to first group them by the second element of each array and then sort each group based on first element, you can do it like this:

```
array = [["34224", "1"], ["20561", "1"], ["26195", "1"], ["32098", "1"], ["33375", "1"], ["34077", "1"], ["34219", "1"], ["34220", "1"], ["34223", "1"], ["19178", "1"], ["33650", "1"], ["33654", "1"], ["33715", "1"], ["33716", "1"], ["33966", "1"], ["33967", "1"], ["33968", "1"], ["34068", "1"], ["34069", "1"], ["34070", "1"], ["34071", "1"], ["34072", "1"], ["34073", "1"], ["34074", "1"], ["34075", "1"], ["34076", "1"], ["33515", "2"], ["33717", "2"], ["33852", "2"], ["33965", "2"], ["34222", "2"]]
hash = array.group_by { |e| e[1] }
hash.keys.each do |key|
  hash[key] = hash[key].sort_by { |e| e[0].to_i }
end
hash  # Final result
```

This is based on assumption that both your first and second elements of the array will be number represented as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) :

```
ids_and_count = [
 ["34224", "1"],["20561", "1"],["26195", "1"],["32098", "1"],
 ["33375", "1"],["34077", "1"],["34219", "1"],["34220", "1"],
 ["34223", "1"],["19178", "1"],["33650", "1"],["33654", "1"],
 ["33715", "1"],["33716", "1"],["33966", "1"],["33967", "1"],
 ["33968", "1"],["34068", "1"],["34069", "1"],["34070", "1"],
 ["34071", "1"],["34072", "1"],["34073", "1"],["34074", "1"],
 ["34075", "1"],["34076", "1"],["33515", "2"],["33717", "2"],
 ["33852", "2"],["33965", "2"],["34222", "2"]]

ids_by_count = ids_and_count.group_by { |_, count| count }.map { |count, ids_and_count_by_count|
  [
    count.to_i,
    ids_and_count_by_count.map { |id, _| id.to_i }.sort
  ]
}.to_h
```

`ids_by_count` is now :

```
{
    1 => [
        19178,
        20561,
        26195,
        32098,
        33375,
        33650,
        33654,
        33715,
        33716,
        33966,
        33967,
        33968,
        34068,
        34069,
        34070,
        34071,
        34072,
        34073,
        34074,
        34075,
        34076,
        34077,
        34219,
        34220,
        34223,
        34224
    ],
    2 => [
        33515,
        33717,
        33852,
        33965,
        34222
    ]
}
```

If you want all the ids that appear twice :

```
ids_by_count[2] # => [33515, 33717, 33852, 33965, 34222]
```